# Указать maven папку с библиотеками

Tags: java, maven, библиотеки, сборка

У меня есть проект `maven`, в котором я подключаю нужные мне библиотеки. У меня есть директория, в которой лежит мой скомпилированный `jar` файл и директория с библиотеками (`libs`). Задача заключается в том, чтобы этот `jar` файл брал библиотеки из этой папки (с подключением библиотек в самом проекте все в порядке). С `maven` начал работать только недавно, нужной информации в гугле не нашел.

`IDE - Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2020.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше наверное будет привести пример. В данном проекте прописано, что при сборке все зависимости будут копировать в директорию `libs`.

Файл `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.somepackage</groupId>
    <artifactId>some-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`Main` класс:

```java
package com.somepackage;

import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.DescriptiveStatistics;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] values = new double[]{1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000};
        DescriptiveStatistics descriptiveStatistics =
                new DescriptiveStatistics();
        for (double v : values) {
            descriptiveStatistics.addValue(v);
        }

        double median = descriptiveStatistics.getPercentile(50);
        System.out.println("Median: " + median);
    }
}
```

Соответственно после сборки проекта мы получим директорию `libs`, в которой будут содержаться все зависимости (`commons-math3-3.6.1.jar`) и файл `some-project-1.0.jar`. Для запуска программы нужно будет выполнить одну из следующих команд.

Windows:

```
java -cp "some-project-1.0.jar;libs/*" com.somepackage.Main
```

Linux:

```
java -cp "some-project-1.0.jar:libs/*" com.somepackage.Main
```

Также можно рассмотреть вариант записи `Main` класса и зависимостей в `MANIFEST.MF`. Для этого необходимо добавить в `pom.xml` следующий фрагмент:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>com.somepackage.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

В результате получим следующий `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Maven Archiver 3.4.0
Build-Jdk-Spec: 11
Class-Path: libs/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar
Main-Class: com.somepackage.Main
```

Соответственно запуск можно будет производить следующим образом:

```
java -jar some-project-1.0.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*Не совсем по теме вопроса. Метод для сборки `war` файла - веб приложения, разделенного на библиотеки.*</sub>

---

Можно собрать и установить один проект в локальный репозиторий `maven` (по умолчанию в папку `.m2`) в виде библиотеки `jar`. У вас может быть несколько таких библиотек. Потом в другом проекте можно будет использовать эти библиотеки как зависимости. Например:

**Первый проект:** библиотека

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <url>https://example.com/module1</url>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
    <name>module1</name>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>module1</finalName>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Второй проект:** приложение

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <url>https://example.com/module2</url>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
    <name>module2</name>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>module2</finalName>
        <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- com.example -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```